# How to show the value of the AUC from geom_density/stat_density

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density, auc

I have produced some density plots using ggplot2 and stat_density.  My colleague mentioned he wasn't convinced that the area under each curve would sum to 1.  So, I set out to calculate the area under the curve, and I am wondering if there might be a better approach than what I did.

Here is an example of what I did:

```
data(iris)

p<-ggplot(iris,aes(x=Petal.Length))+
          stat_density(aes(colour=Species),geom="line",position="identity")

q<-print(p)
q<-q$data[[1]]

# calculate interval between density estimates for a given point.
# assume it is the same interval for all estimates
interval<-q$x[2]-q$x[1] 

# calculate AUC by summing interval*height for the density estimate at each point
tapply(q$density*interval,  
       q$group,
       sum)
```

The result:

```
    1         2         3 
0.9913514 1.0009785 0.9817040
```

It seems to works decently, but I wonder if there is a better way of doing this.  In particular, my calculation of the interval (i.e. dx, I suppose) seems like it could be a problem, especially if the different density curves use different intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way is already good.

Another way to do it is using the trapezoid rule:

```
data <- cbind(q$x, q$y)
by(data, q$group, FUN = function(x) trapz(x[, 1], x[, 2]))
```

The results are nearly the same:

```
INDICES: 1
[1] 0.9903457

INDICES: 2
[1] 1.000978

INDICES: 3
[1] 0.9811152
```

This is because at the bandwidth needed to make the graph of the densities look reasonable (`interval` in your code), you are very close to what you would get if you could do the actual integral.